# MySQL Update Query with Variables with Zend / PDO

Tags: mysql

I have this query that increments a value `index` in existing rows ordered by the value in the column `key`.

```
UPDATE `documents`, (
  SELECT @row_number:=ifnull(@row_number, 0)+1 as `new_index`, `id` 
  FROM `documents`
  WHERE `path` = "/path/to/doc"
  ORDER BY `key`
) AS `table_position`,
(
  SELECT @row_number:=0
) AS `rowNumberInit`
SET `index` = `table_position`.`new_index`
WHERE `table_position`.`id` = `documents`.`id`
```

and I use this PHP code to execute it:

```
/** @var PDO $pdo */
$ret = $pdo->query($sql);
// Now every value in column `index` is set to 1
$res = $ret->execute();
// Now every value in column `index` is counted up
```

This doesn't look quite like the right way to do it.

I currently use PDO directly, because `Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql` seems to wreak havoc with this query.

In addition to that I'd like to have the "/path/to/doc" string in the `WHERE` clause a a bind param. Replacing it by a `?` and passing the value to `execute()` didn't work.

How would I do this correctly with Zend or PDO?

Comment: @your-common-sense Why did you remove the php, pdo and zend tags? This question ist not about MySQL, because the query works. It's about how to run this query using PHPs PDO and/or ZF correcly.

Comment: PDO doesn't add anything on its own, it just sends your query to database, as is. There is no whatever "correct way"  for this specific query - to PDO all queries are the same.